# Left click activates on any other mouse command

Tags: windows, motherboard, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

### Background

IBM ThinkPad R51
Windows XP Professional (though the issue is not OS dependent)

Initially, if powered off (battery disconnected) for a period of time, the computer would return with an incorrect BIOS date along with a checksum error. Both of these most likely relate to a bad motherboard battery, but the errors might be relevant to this issue.

When operating the computer after being fully dead, the left click action no longer works. Using either the trackpad or the left click key do nothing.

I opened the computer up and checked the ribbon connection to the motherboard, but it appeared like it was intact.

A PnP USB mouse in Windows worked fine. (likely because it overrides the trackpad mouse)

I then tried booting into a Debian live USB and the issue was still occurring, except now the USB mouse left click wouldn't work either. (likely because it doesn't override)

Since the issue was occurring on different OSes I figured it might have something to do with the motherboard.

This IBM Thinkpad has a recovery section with PCDoctor on it. I ran a mouse diagnostic test and it appears that whenever something is moved with the mouse (trackpad, buttons, trackpoint), the left click activates and stays activated.

If it's any clue, by switching the primary and secondary keys on windows, the left click key becomes operable to do the right click function, yet the right key locks up same as the left key did earlier. (Indicating that this isn't a hardware problem, but some sort of OS-independent software problem)

EDIT: I should also note that I tried disabling the TrackPoint feature in BIOS but this had no effect on the issue.

### Question

What could be causing this issue?

Thanks ahead!

**UPDATE:** By disabling and re-enabling the left-click key in the ThinkPad mouse configuration utility, I was able to regain use of the left-click functionality (hopefully permanently). If someone has any ideas as to why this happened, please let me know.